fail2ban error (sshd jail)
I am making my own VPN on VDS with a script 3x-ui. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. I also want to connect it so that it would be impossible for several users to connect using the same configuration. I set an access log for "./access.log" via 3x-ui, but such an error was found.

Configuration: Have not found any log file for sshd jail
I tried to solve the problem through the ChatGPT, it advised me to create a jail file and write it there, but in the end the error remains.


[Edit] your question to include the relevant configuration. Use the {} to format text. Do not use pictures.
